# Using enum inside header in c

Tags: c, struct, enums, header, incomplete-type

i'm having a little bit of trouble trying to use enum inside header in c. Here's how my code look like

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "listaEstatica.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CACHORRO Tobias;
    strcpy(Tobias.nome, "Tobias");
    Tobias.registro = 123456789;
    Tobias.idade = 6;
    inserir(Tobias);

    exibirCachorro(cachorros[0]);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

listaEstatica.c

```
#include "listaEstatica.h"

fim = 0;

enum Porte { Pequeno, Medio, Grande };
enum Estado { Machucado, Doente, DoencaInfeccosa};

int vazia() {
    if (fim == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void inserir(CACHORRO cachorro) {
    if (fim == MAX) {
        printf("Não inseriu %s, lista cheia\n", cachorro.nome);
    } else {
        cachorros[fim] = cachorro;
        fim++;
        printf("Inserido %s OK\n", cachorro.nome);
    }
}

void exibirCachorro(CACHORRO cachorro) {
    printf("Nome: %s\n", cachorro.nome);
    printf("Registro: %i\n", cachorro.registro);
    printf("Idade: %i\n", cachorro.idade);
}
```

listaEstatica.h

```
typedef struct {
    char nome[30];
    int registro;
    int idade;
    enum Porte porte;
    enum Estado estado;
} CACHORRO;

int fim;
#define MAX 3
CACHORRO cachorros[MAX];

int vazia();

void inserir(CACHORRO cachorro);

void exibirCachorro(CACHORRO cachorro);
```

Trying to compile this game me the following error

```
 listaEstatica.h:5:16: error: field ‘porte’ has incomplete type
     enum Porte porte;
            ^
 listaEstatica.h:6:17: error: field ‘estado’ has incomplete type
     enum Estado estado;
```

Thanks in advance, any help is welcome

Comment: move the enum declarations to the header file. Right now the declaration is given after the use of it, since an include litterally just copyies the contents of the header file into the .c file when compiling

Comment: Try to use a `typedef` like this: `typedef enum {Pequeno, Medio, Grande} Porte;`

Comment: @Cyclone no, you don't need to do that. EDIT: that still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht moving the declaration to the header worked flawlessly, thank you so much

Comment: this line: 'CACHORRO cachorros[MAX];' actually defines some data in the header file.   That should 'never' be done. Define the data in a .c file (and if needed) use an 'extern' statement in the header file.  Depending on the compiler and parameters used.  There could be multiple instances of that cachorros[] data within the program.

Comment: this line, 'cachorros[fim] = cachorro;' at best, only copies some pointers.  Suggest using memcpy() to copy the struct contents

Comment: it is a very bad idea to pass (or return) a struct of any significant size (say greater than 4 bytes).   Instead, pass a pointer to the struct.  (this will require modification to the related function signatures and modification of the associated code to use 'name->field' type statements rather than 'name.field' expressions

Comment: it is not a good programming practice to have type definitions and variable names only differ in the capitalization.   (It makes for some major misunderstandings and errors when performing debug and/or maintenance

Comment: this line: 'int main(int argc, char** argv) {' will cause the compiler to raise two warnings about unused parameters.   Suggest changing line to: 'int main( void ) {'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, that you're using a enum that's not yet known to the compiler, due to the order of your code.

An include literally just copies the contents of the header file into the .c file. So in your case you have your struct definition with these two enums and a few lines further down the enums are defined. So for the compiler the enums don't exist at the time it reaches the struct.

Move the enums into the header file and before the struct definition.

Answer (score 0):

suggest,

define the two enum types before the typedef in the header file.

otherwise, the compiler does not know the contents/meaning of the two enum statements in the typedef struct definition